# Zooming and directions services

Tags: android, iphone, google-maps-api-3

I’m looking to force Google direction service to zoom to the final destination rather than show the entire route.  Is this possible?  If so how would you go about doing this?  I would also like to remove the markers I set once the start and end locations have been set and the calculate route function is called is this possible?  I don’t think any of the code will help it’s done in v3.  I have been searching and found nothing related to the zoom issue.  Can anyone please help…

Answer (score 0):

First pass these options when intializing the directionsRenderer:

```
{suppressMarkers:true,preserveViewport:true}
```

...so you will not get markers and the map will not fit to the bounds of the route when rendering.

Then, after rendering the route(  `setDirections()` ), call this:

```
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        //set the center of the map to the end of the route
      map.setCenter(response.routes[0].legs[response.routes[0].legs.length-1].end_location);
        //set the zoom to the desired value
```

(where directionsDisplay is the directionsRenderer-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Well this did help, now looking at it hough, i think maybe should have add my code. i'm going to try it in here first.  I would like the "A" & "B" markers to stay i have built arrays for othere markers that i would like to suppress once the calculateroute function is handeld or have a button that turns them on and off that wont clear the map or add additional turn by turn directions.